# Tensorflow 2.0-GPU Windows is running training code on the CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Currently I am using on **Tensorflow 2.0**. Here is my PC:

- CPU: i5-4690 3.5Ghz.
- RAM: 16GB.
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 1050Ti 4GB.
- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.
- CUDA 10.0 & cuDNN 7.4.

My project is an image classification project using **ResNet50** and **CIFAR100 Dataset**.

I build the network using subclassing (the code snippet was too long so I did not attach it on this question) and loaded the data using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

```
def load_cifar100(batch_size, num_classes=100):
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()

    x_train, x_test = x_train.astype('float32') / 255, x_test.astype('float32') / 255

    x_val, y_val = x_train[-10000:], y_train[-10000:]
    x_train, y_train = x_train[:-10000], y_train[:-10000]

    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
    y_val = to_categorical(y_val, num_classes)

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

    val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
    val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)

    test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))
    test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size)

    return train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset
```

I used `GradientTape` for setup my training process:

```
def training(x_batch, y_batch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x_batch, training=True)
        loss_val = loss(y_batch, logits)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss_val, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    train_acc_metric(y_batch, logits)


for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_acc_metric.reset_states()
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        training(x_batch_train, y_batch_train)

    train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
    template = 'Epoch {}, Train_Acc: {}'
    print(template.format(epoch + 1,
                          train_acc))
```

During training, I saw that my `GPU` did not work at all [Pic1], and all the training process just put into the `CPU` even though I turn on the debug config `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)` and seem like all the layers were loaded to `GPU` [Pic2].

[image: GPU not working]

[image: Tensorflow logs]

**UPDATE:**

Here is what the GPU looks like when I change to `model.fit` function. And the training time for each epoch was way faster then `GradientTape`:
[image: RUn on model.fit]

Comment: Python seems to be using 11% of the GPU, and 25% of the CPU, so yes, it is running on the GPU, I do not see the issue. Do not fall into the misconception of thinking 0% CPU and 100% GPU.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro ah when I use ```model.fit```, the GPU will run more than that and the training process will be bit faster.

Comment: One thing you have to keep in mind is that not all the processes are good to be parallelized on GPU, so in tensorflow, the framework it self takes care of this. That is why you see some methods use GPU more than CPU and some methods use GPU less. Frameworks like PyTorch does not take care of this, and somehow the overall routine for PyTorch is a little different than TensorFlow.

Comment: @Shahryar so you mean when Tensorflow already detected the GPU, the framework itself will know how to control between CPU and GPU and not always just run on GPU ?

Comment: @TrungTínTrần Yes that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to check before starting the training process if Tensorflow (TF2) uses GPUs, via:

```
assert tf.test.is_gpu_available()
assert tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

Comment: Reason for downvoting?

Comment: All the return are True but it's still the same, CPU still run full 1 core and GPU 1-2%.

Comment: @TrungTínTrần What's your batch size?

Comment: ```batch_size=16``` & ```epochs=100``` sir

Comment: @TrungTínTrần The small batch size can be a reason for low GPU usage, moreover (generally speaking) it's better to use the highest API available where possible because they take care of several low-level details. However, in order to check if your NN is training on GPU, you have to use the assertions stated above.